# How to return all possible paths of random binary tree in Python

Tags: python, random, tree, binary-tree

I have a random binary tree in the following forms

12

13, 14

29, 26, 89

Each node has two children i.e ( 12->(13, 14), 13->(29, 26), 14 ->(26, 89)). Here I need to return  all possible paths  in the forms [ [12, 13, 29], [ 12, 13, 26], [12, 14, 26], [12, 14, 89]].  I tried with the following code.  I have problem with updating list.  Thanks in advance.

```
class Tree:

    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __str_(self):
        return '%s' % self.data

def makeList(tree, path =[]):
    if(tree != None):
        path.append(tree.data)
        if tree.left:
            path.append(makeList(tree.left, path))
        if tree.right:
            path.append(makeList(tree.left, path))

    return path
```

root = Tree(12)

root.left = Tree(13)

root.right = Tree(14)

root.right.left = Tree(26)

root.left.right =  Tree(26)

root.left.left = Tree(29)

root.right.right = Tree(86)

```
x = makeList(root)
```

Comment: If `26` is connected both to `13` and `14` this is not a binary tree! (in a binary tree each node has, at most, one parent).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how to solve it using a [memoized recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). But  I still post my answer since it may solve your problem partly.

```
def makeList(tree):
    paths = []
    if not (tree.left or tree.right):
        return [[tree.data]]
    if tree.left:
        paths.extend([[tree.data] + child for child in makeList(tree.left)])
    if tree.right:
        paths.extend([[tree.data] + child for child in makeList(tree.right)])
    return paths
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set this:

```
def makeList(tree, path =[]):
```

This empty list after path is not deleted after the execution of the function, if you call makeList a second time without a path parameter, the path list you had at the end of the first call will remain.

Consider the function:

```
def f(l=[]):
    l.append(17)
    print l
```

If you keep on calling f() without the parameter l you will get another 17 each time.

```
[17]
[17, 17]
[17, 17, 17]
```

Comment: Here how function can be a list even without its return list?.